# How can we find all field names exist in several tables, and field names that exist in one table, but not in other tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some basic DDL here.

```
--Drop Table tableA
--Drop Table tableB
--Drop Table tableC

Create table dbo.tableA
(
Id int, 
Name varchar(100),
Code varchar(5),
Address varchar(100),
RegDate datetime,
AddedBy varchar(50)
)

Create table dbo.tableB
(
Id int, 
Name varchar(100),
KeyCode varchar(5),
Address varchar(100),
RegDate datetime,
AddedBy varchar(50)
)

Create table dbo.tableC
(
Id int, 
FName varchar(100),
LName varchar(100),
Address varchar(100),
)

select * from tableA
select * from tableB
select * from tableC
```

Now, this should tell me what field names are common to all three tables.

```
select
   syscolumns.name as [Column]
from 
   sysobjects 
inner join 
   syscolumns on sysobjects.id = syscolumns.id
where sysobjects.xtype = 'u'
and   sysobjects.name = 'tableA' 
INTERSECT
select
   syscolumns.name as [Column]
from 
   sysobjects 
inner join 
   syscolumns on sysobjects.id = syscolumns.id
where sysobjects.xtype = 'u'
and   sysobjects.name = 'tableB' 
INTERSECT
select
   syscolumns.name as [Column]
from 
   sysobjects 
inner join 
   syscolumns on sysobjects.id = syscolumns.id
where sysobjects.xtype = 'u'
and   sysobjects.name = 'tableC'
```

Number 1) Is there an easier way to do this, with less code. It would be hard to scale out to multiple tables.

Number 2) How can I tell what field name is in one table, but not in the others? I tried using the EXCEPT clause and the results look, well, very inaccurate.

Comment: Field name? Databases have columns :)

Comment: Please don't use `syscolumns` and `sysobjects`, these have been deprecated for _seventeen years_.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, should INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS be used now?

Comment: @jarlh [only if you want incomplete data](https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views) and views that Microsoft's own documentation suggests could produce unreliable data, or absolutely need metadata queries that will only support a subset of functionality across more than one platform. Within SQL Server you should use the newer catalog views, e.g. `sys.columns`, `sys.objects`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a `GROUP BY`, use the `HAVING` clause to decide 1 or 3 table columns.

```
select
   syscolumns.name as [Column]
from 
   sysobjects 
inner join 
   syscolumns on sysobjects.id = syscolumns.id
where sysobjects.xtype = 'u'
and   sysobjects.name IN ('tableA', 'tableB', 'tableC')
GROUP BY syscolumns.name
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;  -- 1 for unique column names,
                      -- 3 for 3 table column names
```

**Note:** Aaron Bertrand says '*you should use the newer catalog views, e.g. sys.columns, sys.objects, etc*'.